# Select default view on charts as 1month rather than all

Tags: highcharts

How can one set the default view of time-series chart as 1month rather than appearing all by default?

Many thanks

Comment: Could you add more details to the question? what you tried so far, code, example etc

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `selected` property:

```
rangeSelector: {
  selected: 0
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gqdrh7se/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/rangeSelector.selected